# Universal property of the category of quasicoherent sheaves of a blowup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, noncommutative-geometry

We know that if $Z \rightarrow X$ is a closed subscheme of X of ideal $\mathcal{I}$, then if $\pi : Bl_Z X \rightarrow X$ is the projection, $\pi^* \mathcal{I}$ is invertible. Does the category of quasicoherent sheaves on $Bl_Z X$ satisfies some kind of universal property universally inverting $\mathcal{I}$ for instance ?
I guess I am asking for a non-commutative counterpart of the blowup construction ?

Comment: The sheaf $\pi^*(I)$ is not invertible. The invertible sheaf in question is the image of the natural morphism from $\pi^*(I)$ to the structure sheaf of the blowup.

Comment: @Sacha ty for the answer. My mistake it is. But the question still holds, I can say that the image is universally invertible or something similar. I have no idea of what nice universal property it should satisfy though.

Comment: For the tensor(!)-categories of quasi-coherent sheaves, something along those lines is certainly shown in M. Brandenburg's thesis.

Comment: @Ben oh this is cool thank you that's exactly what I was looking for (it is 5.10.19 and 5.10.22 of his thesis)

Comment: Dear @NikolaTomić, I'm glad this was helpful. Someone should write up an answer for you to accept, then. Now that you've looked up the details, you could just do that by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ben suggested to me, here is an answer:

The result is available in Martin Brandenburg's thesis [*Tensor categorical foundations of algebraic geometry*].

So let $\mathcal{C}$ be a symmetric monoidal category (He calls it a tensor category), the unit will be denoted by $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{C}$.
The universal property I was looking for exists is some form but it is more subtle than that. So instead of invertible objects, Brandenburg talk about line objects:

A **line object** in a tensor category $\mathcal{C}$ is an invertible object $X$ that is aswell symtrivial, it means that the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ acts trivially on $X^{\otimes n}$ for each $n$.

In a locally presentable category, there is a regular epi-mono factorization, so it is possible to define the image of a morphism $f : X\rightarrow Y$ to be the unique object $Z$ such that $f$ factors through $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$ where the first arrow is a regular epimorphism and the second one is a monomorphism.

For a map $X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mathcal{C}$, the image will be denoted $X \cdot \mathcal{O}_\mathcal{C}$.
The universal property can be stated as follow:

The **blow-up** of a locally presentable category $\mathcal{C}$ along an ideal $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{C}$ is the weakly initial locally presentable tensor category $\mathcal{D}$ with a cocontinuous functor $F : \mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ such that $F(\mathcal{I})\cdot\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{D}$ is a line object. If it exists, we write it $Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(\mathcal{C})$.

Then Brandenburg claims that if we restrict ourselves to balanced tensor categories (the one such that epis and monos are isos) (I don't really know why but it is for Proj constructions for categories to work I guess, so for the categorical blow-up to exists), then the blow-up exists and we have that:

$$Qcoh(Bl_{I}(X)) \simeq Bl_{I}(Qcoh{X})$$
so the category of quasi-coherent sheaves of the blow-up satisfies a "making I a line object"-like universal property.